# Setting a countdown in the popup HTML from the background JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to display a countdown in the popup html, that should be monitored by the background.js

I've found a javascript code that I adapted to my need, to run in the background script. I tried to put it directly into the popup.htm but it somehow didn't worked (and would also let me try to do parameter passing, which is not a bad idea as I'm trying to slowly learn how to do coding)

Here is the JS:

```
var Countdowntimer = 1;
var countDownDate = new Date().getTime()+(Countdowntimer*60*1000+5);
var x = setInterval(function() {

  var now = new Date().getTime();

  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    var ongoing = document.getElementById("main-cd").innerHTML = "Refreshing...";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Here is the html:

```
<h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Time before next refresh: </strong></h3>
<h1 id="main-cd"></h1>
<script src="background.js" />
```

I'm getting the following error message: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at background.js:29

I expect the countdown to be displayed in the pop up and updated whenever the seconds changes.

Thanks by advance for the help !

Comment: I guess you've used background.js in several places like a content script, which is wrong. Add your manifest.json to the question. Also note, the popup runs only when shown, and it's a separate window with its own devtools (accessible by right-clicking inside the popup).

Comment: Ok, so how can I pass the countdown from the background script, to the .json, to the html ? Or maybe I should just pass the  variable countDownDate (the target date) to the HTML, et calculate the countdown only when needed ? I've used the background script for a loop that refreshes every tabs containing a matching URL, should I have done that in the content script ?

I never passed a parameter from a file to the other (js to json or html), so I thought passing it straight from the js to the html was the best solution ^^

Comment: JS+Html is just one context but extensions consist of separate isolated contexts so to pass the data you need to use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or [storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). I think it might make sense to get to know the architecture of extensions either by studying the [official intro](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) or some other tutorial.

Comment: Ok, seems like a legit answer ! Thanks for your help, and for the links !